# MPI program deadlocks on blocking send/recv with certain amounts of processes

Tags: c, mpi, deadlock, blocking

I'm writing a distributed branch and bound tsp algorithm. The idea is that processes can find a better bound, and when they do they can send it to the other processes. I implemented this with Isend en Ircv and this works fine.

The second part of my code outputs the best found solution. My slave processes send their best solution to my master, and my master checks if the received solution is better. This is implemented with the blocking send and receive:

```
bestSolution = calloc(amount, sizeof(int));
bestSolution[0] = INT_MAX;

recSolution = calloc(amount, sizeof(int));
recSolution[0] = INT_MAX;

//...

MPI_Init(&argc, (char ***) &argv);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &processId);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &amountOfProcesses);

//...

if (processId != 0){
    MPI_Send(bestSolution, amount, MPI_INT, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    //print FINAL BEST sent
}

if (processId == 0){
    for (int i = 1; i < amountOfProcesses; i++){
        //print starting to receive
        MPI_Recv(recSolution, amount, MPI_INT, i, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &recStatus);
        //print final best received
        //do stuff with recSolution
    }
}

// ...

// print dead
MPI_finalize();
```

All variables contain the right data upon sending and if the data is receives, the received variable contains the right stuff. The only problem is the following (part of my debugging output with 4 processes):

```
2: FINAL BEST sent: 387
2 dead
3: FINAL BEST sent: 345
3 dead
0: starting to receive 1...
0: final best received: 345
0: starting to receive 2...
1: FINAL BEST sent: 345
1 dead
```

So the code deadlocks on process 0 trying to receive the message of process 2.

The weird part: it works perfectly with 3 or 5 processes, but it deadlocks every time when I use 4 processes. Every process reaches this part of the code without any problems on any amount of processes, so I don't think the problem resides in the code that happens before this part of my program is executed.

Why is this code deadlocking? Since I don't get any mpi warnings/errors, it's pretty straight forward usage of message passing and the available memory is not an issue, I'm at a loss here.

Comment: I don't see any errors. Can you show code for array allocating and processId initialization?

Comment: I've added the extra information.

Comment: It is strange. This code works for me. I've added to it headers and main() and it runs fine.

Comment: That's the thing that baffles me. The code works on 40-ish different input files, only this one file with an amount of 4 processes fails to work.

Comment: Which MPI implementation are you using?

Comment: There was a problem in the Isend/Irecv part of my application which caused this deadlock to happen. I don't understand why, since I only use blocking send and receive here, but the problem is solved now. For the record, the code pasted here is indeed correct OpenMPI code, my error was located elsewhere.

Comment: You need to keep in mind that an `MPI_Isend` from one process can match to an `MPI_Recv` on another process, and vice versa, and for any other pairing of send and receive routines. If there was an outstanding _unmatched_ send or receive where you weren't expecting one, then that could produce all manner of weird result.

Comment: I had some issues with similar code a few years back and it basically required an `MPI_Barrier()` before the `MPI_Finalize()` to make sure that all processes finished. At that point was a bug in MPI itself; make sure you don't run into something similar.